# 'IN' clause with multiple 'AND' Condition

Tags: php, sql

I have a SQL query which is returning me an incorrect result.

```
" SELECT * FROM directory WHERE '".$_REQUEST['occupation']."' IN (occupation,pro_cat1,pro_cat2,pro_cat3,pro_cat4,pro_cat5) AND state = '".$_REQUEST['state']."' AND city = '".$_REQUEST['city']."' AND status = 1 ORDER BY rand() "
```

Here I want to check if `occupation` is one of the 6 values provided in the `IN` clause (while also adding some more clauses in the `WHERE` concatenated with an `AND`).

It does return me a result, however it is incorrect. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: `It's giving me a result but its not a proper result` ... what about the result isn't proper?

Comment: its not searching in all occupation,pro_cat1,pro_cat2,pro_cat3,pro_cat4,pro_cat5

Comment: You are vulnerable to sql injection attack. I suggest you read about prepared statements.

Comment: So occupation, pro_cat1, etc. are columns in table directory? And you want to select rows for the given state and city and the given occupation equals at least the content of one of these columns? This is what the query does. Or do you want something else?

Answer (score 4):

If the values you are looking for are strings, you need to quote them:

```
... IN ('occupation','pro_cat1','pro_cat2','pro_cat3','pro_cat4','pro_cat5') ...
        ^ here     ^ etc.
```

You should also never inject variables directly into a query. Instead you should use a prepared statement with placeholders for your variables.

Also, column names should not be quoted (unless they are reserved words, contain spaces, etc.) but if you need to quote them, you should use back-ticks:

```
... directory where `".$_REQUEST['occupation']."` IN ...
                    ^ here                      ^
```

Also note that table- and column names cannot be prepared so they always have to be white-listed before you inject them into your query.